# How do I add a 'don't show this message again' checkbox with localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap alert.

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Don't show this again!
    </label>
</div>
```

If the checkbox is clicked and alert is dissmissed

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
```

I don't want to show the alert ever again. I am wondering if this can be done with 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

```
$('#checkbox').click(function() {
    if ($('#checkbox').attr('checked')) {
        document.cookie="alert=dismiss";
    }
})
```

and then if there is a cookie hide the message `$.hide` method?

**Updated with Solution**

```
var oldBrowser = $.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.versionNumber) < 9;

//message is dismissed via storage
var dissmissed = amplify.store("DoNotShowMessageAgain");

// if oldbrowers and not dismissed
if (oldBrowser && !dissmissed) {
     $( "#browserAlert" ).show();
}


// Don't show message again
$('#browserAlert .close').click(function(){
if ($('.checkbox input').is(':checked')) {
     amplify.store( "DoNotShowMessageAgain", true );
 }
})
```

Comment: Yes - you can do it with cookies.  You might want to spend a little more time on the cookie assignment code to ensure existing cookies are not overwritten.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use HTML5's local storage for this.  Its very purpose is a modern way to persist data between sessions for a browser with no expiration:

```
function localStorageAvailable() {
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

$('#checkbox').click(function(){
    if ($('#checkbox').attr('checked')) {
        if (localStorageAvailable())
            localStorage.DoNotShowMessageAgain = "true";
    }
})
```

And then then, when the page is ready, you would want to check and restore the functionality from a past saved experience:

```
if (localStorageAvailable()) {
    if (localStorage.DoNotShowMessageAgain && localStorage.DoNotShowMessageAgain === "true") {
        // user doesn't want to see the message again, so handle accordingly
    }
};
```

For more information on HTML5's local storage, take a look at [my blog post](http://tstringer.azurewebsites.net/?p=2271) on the topic.

Comment: would local storage work on IE9,IE8 below. The message is actually to so that look at out browser compatibly chart because they are accessing the site using incompatible old browser

Comment: HTML5 web storage is available in IE8 and above: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: Ok thanks I have updated the question with my progress.. and IT WORKS. But let me know if I am missing something?

Comment: It looks like that is sufficient, but to be honest I directly use web storage instead of with amplifyjs.  But it seems to solve the same problem, so if your testing proves success, it looks good.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like the app already has amplifyjs, thus i used it. But i do need to learn how to use it directly.